# Add permanent SSL certificate exception in Chrome (Linux)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ssl, certificate, exceptions

I have a problem with a website that has an SSL certificate which doesn't correspond to the website domain. Chrome gives me a warning for this website (and rightly so), which I have to ignore manually. Every time I restart Chrome, I need to ignore the certificate issue again.

I've tried adding the certificate as a trusted one with `certutil`, using `C,,` and `P,,` trustargs, but it doesn't work. I can't find a set of trustargs that will tell it to ignore which domain is using the certificate.

Is there a way to tell Chrome (or certutil) to trust this certificate whatever domain uses it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is a summary of the answers from the thread
[Disable Google Chrome warning if security certificate is not trusted](https://superuser.com/questions/27268/disable-google-chrome-warning-if-security-certificate-is-not-trusted).

> You can avoid the message for trusted sites by installing the certificate.
>   This can be done by clicking on the warning icon in the address bar, then click
>       `Certificate Information -> Details Tab -> Export...`
>   Save the certificate.
>
> Use Chrome's `Preferences -> Under The Hood -> Manage Certificates -> Import`.
>   On the "Certificate Store" screen of the
>   import, choose "Place all certificates
>   in the following store" and browse for
>   "Trusted Root Certification
>   Authorities." Restart Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, but this only works on Windows. On Linux, Chrome uses the `certutil` command line tool to manage certificates, nothing else.

Comment: It seems I can't select your answer as the right one anymore because the bounty expired :'(

Comment: @Raphink: Does this work after all in Linux?

Comment: No, it doesn't work on Linux, and the bounty cannot be relaunched.

Comment: FYI, this (now?) does work on Chromium 18, Ubuntu 12.04 - same instructions found here: http://superuser.com/a/41937/55046

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I just wish it was easier, 1 click ideally :-)

Comment: 2 quick things to add to this:

1. It seems to work best if you go to the "Authorities" tab in the certificate manager, before clicking "Import..." (thus adding you, or whoever signed the certificate, as a trusted signer-of-certificates)

2. I'm not sure if I needed to, but I checked all the checkboxes under "Edit trust settings".

Comment: Worked like a charm, never considered it thank you!

Comment: There is no certificate information any more in recent chrome versions.

Comment: @user1050755: What do you mean? AFAIK certificates are reachable via Settings > Show advanced settings > HTTPS/SSL > Manage certificates.

Comment: @user1050755 Dev Tools (F12) > Security tab > View Certificate

Answer (score 16):

Using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 on Linux:

1. First click on the certificate warning and export the certificate to your file system. (Connection > Certificate Information > Details > Export)
2. Then use [certutil](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxCertManagement) in order to add this saved certificate as a trusted peer:

   ```
   certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t P -n <certificate nickname> -i <certificate filename>
   ```
3. Restart Chrome and you're done.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I had to run this first (opensuse linux): `sudo zypper install mozilla-nss-tools`

Comment: This is a great answer, if you want to understand better how it works, use `certutil -H -A`, and maybe read about trust flags in NSS Database: https://blogs.oracle.com/meena/entry/notes_about_trust_flags

Comment: to install certutil i used sudo apt-get install libnss3-tools

Answer (score 12):

The only way I got it working in Chromium with Ubuntu Linux is using this certutil commandline:

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "CP,CP," -n CertNickName -i cert_file.crt
```

Comment: This worked for me using Arch too.

Comment: That worked for me on Centos 7

Comment: Worked Debian 9 also (requires libnss3-tools package installed first).

Comment: Worked for me on Debian 11

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 22.04, Chrome 120...

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at this thread:
[Can't convince Chrome that my Tivo's self signed certificate is ok](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28673).

The article remarks that:

> You need to specify the "C,," trust flags to work around the NSS bug.

If this thread does relate to your problem, it looks like this is a known bug in Chrome, where the "P,," trust flags is not working: 
[libpkix ignores the P (trusted peer) trust flag](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=531160)

I hope this helps (I'm answering a bit blindly, since I'm not on Linux).

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be related to my problem, and hence a bug in Chrome. I'll consider your suggestion as an answer to my question, even though it doesn't really fix my problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome in Linux doesn’t have a SSL certificate manager, it relies on the NSS Shared DB. In order to add SSL certificates to the database you will have to use the command line. I will explain how you can add the CAcert certificates and a very easy way to add self-signed certificates.

Please have a look at this thread: 
[blog.avirtualhome.com/2010/02/02/adding-ssl-certificates-to-google-chrome-linux-ubuntu/](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2010/02/02/adding-ssl-certificates-to-google-chrome-linux-ubuntu/)

Comment: You should move the stuff from the blog post into here.  Currently as it stands this is pretty much a link-only answer.

Comment: -1 Need to explain here. Links die. This will live.

Comment: aaaaand the link is dead.

Comment: Looks like the waybackmachine captured it :)
https://web.archive.org/web/20121020174226/http://blog.avirtualhome.com/adding-ssl-certificates-to-google-chrome-linux-ubuntu/