# store ssl certs with google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to add a sites "ssl cert" like in Firefox:

[image]

in Google Chrome?

Comment: It depends on the OS.

Comment: ok, then e.g.: Fedora or winxp or obsd? :O

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [Add permanent SSL certificate exception in Chrome (linux)](https://superuser.com/questions/104146/add-permanent-ssl-certificate-exception-in-chrome-linux)

It's titled about linux, but the accepted answer should work both on windows and Linux now with a recent Chrome build (there's a certificate manager under Preferences -> Under the hood).

Not sure about BSDs.