# How to trust a self-signed ssl root CA in Chrome on Debian via terminal?

Tags: google-chrome, debian, ssl

I am setting up a dedicated machine to automate browser benchmarks of my web application. This needs to use HTTP/2 which requires an SSL connection so I have created a self signed CA and certificate for my local https server to use.

I added my self signed certificate to Debian, which seems to work as expected. It seems Chrome uses a built-in certificate store when on Linux that you add to via its GUI.

The issue is, my environment is a VPS running Debian so I cannot access the Chrome UI to add certificates via its UI.

I have installed my self signed root certificate to my system using the following commands:

```
$ sudo cp localhost.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localhost.crt
$ sudo update-ca-certificates

Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

Now when hitting the server via `curl`, requests trust the self signed certificate

```
$ curl https://localhost:3000

<html></html>
```

However when using headless Chrome via Puppeteer, Chrome does not accept the certificate and exits.

I am aware that I can configure Puppeteer to ignore SSL warnings - this does result in different browser behaviours (particularly in terms of caching) so I cannot use it for my use case (automated performance benchmarks).

I know that under Linux, Chrome uses a built in certificate store. Is it possible to add to that store via terminal?

EDIT:

I tried to use `certutil` following the instructions from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/104146/add-permanent-ssl-certificate-exception-in-chrome-linux)

```
$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t P -n localhost -i /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localhost.crt
```

`-d` is the database and I verified that `sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb` exists. `-A` Adds a certificate to the database, `-t P` says to mark it as a "trusted peer", `-n` is a nickname for the cert and `-i` is the cert path.

However upon rerunning the Puppeteer process, it still did not accept the certificate. Restarting the computer doesn't seem to change anything.

EDIT:

The following command worked. `-t CP` adds the cert as a trusted peer and CA. I don't know what the commas mean.

```
$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "CP,CP," -n localhost -i /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localhost.crt
```

Comment: You can answer your own question.  That's better than leaving this dangling as an unanswered one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command worked.

First ensure `certutil` is installed with:

```
sudo apt install libnss3-tools
```

Then add the cert to the db:

```
$ certutil \
  -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb \
  -A \
  -t "CP,CP," \
  -n localhost \
  -i /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localhost-ca.crt
```

`-t CP` adds the cert as a trusted peer and CA. I don't know what the commas in `-t "CP,CP,"` mean but it doesn't work without them.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I was using `-t "C,,"` and `-t "CP,,"` fixed the issue with the latest Chrome/Chromium for me.