# How do I disable the warning Chrome gives if a security certificate is not trusted without showing errors?

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, https

Asking again because I don't have enough reputation to [post the answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/27268/how-do-i-disable-the-warning-chrome-gives-if-a-security-certificate-is-not-trust).

Answer (score 0):

It took a lot of fiddling but eventually I found a combination of flags that **works in 2021!**

This tells Chrome to ignore all SSL errors, disables the "*Chrome is being controlled by automated test software*" message and starts in full screen.
Add it to the Target field of your shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --test-type=webdriver --start-fullscreen
```